# Eric T. Sawyer's proof of Fourier restriction conjecture

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Some days ago Eric T. Sawyer uploaded a paper to arxiv claiming a proof of the Fourier restriction conjecture https://arxiv.org/pdf/2311.03145.pdf. If complete and correct this work will be a landmark in analysis.

Now the restriction conjecture has long been studied, but was still considered wide open. So what are the key ideas that this proof brings that cracked the problem? How does it obtain the necessary geometric information to solve the Kakeya problem? What would a heuristic overview of this proof look like in simplest terms?

Comment: Good thing he cites Tao now instead of Tau.

Comment: Like with the Yitang Zhang work, it is better to let experts digest and discuss this and eventually I am sure write some blog posts. It seems a bit too early still.

Comment: For anyone who wants to see the abstract without downloading the full pdf document, https://arxiv.org/abs/2311.03145

Comment: The claim of the proof of the conjecture has been withdrawn: https://arxiv.org/abs/2311.03145v5